# Facebook Messenger Platform welcome screen not showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger

My bot is working and able to reply to messages, but now I'm trying to add functionality for responding to a postback from the "Get Sarted" button.

I can't get the "Get Started" button to show up, though.

[This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36832261/1814949) suggests deleting the conversation on desktop and opening a new one, but this doesn't work: it just creates an empty conversation, without the welcome message or "Get Started" button. The documentation linked in that answer is also no longer available.

So how do I get this view to show up, so I can create and test my response to a user clicking the "Get Started" button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the "Get Started" button before it shows up:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
    }    
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Comment: i have the same problem, it did work for me, but after changing the Webhooks URL it doesn't.  `{"result":"Successfully added new_thread's CTAs"}`